# Custom exception handle with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here,my requirement is that i want separate code in my application for exception handling,i saw  a nice option of spring there using @controller advice to handle exceptions globally.

```
@ControllerAdvice

class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  // 409
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

But there i want to cutomization there,like proper dynamic messages,own error code. so how can i do this,i am new to spring boot and even i don't have knowledge of spring.Need basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come up with a class like this to capture information to be sent in response in case of exception:-

```
public class APIResponse  {
     int errorCode;
     String description;
     String someInformation;
     // any other information that you want to send back in case of exception.
}


@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  // 409
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public APIResponse handleConflict(DataIntegrityViolationException exception) {
        APIResponse  response = createResponseFromException(exception);
        return response;
    }
}
```

In your controller advice class:-

1. Have the return type APIResponse instead of void.
2. The handler method can have the exception raised as the argument.
3. Using the exception object to create the APIResponse object.
4. Put @ResponseBody on the handler method.